# Why does defining a virtual destructor to an abstract class add a byte to the .bss segment?

Tags: c++, memory, compilation

I'm trying to create elf file that only has a text section. I was in the process of fixing compiler warnings of object of abstract class type which has non virtual destructor will cause undefined behavior, and I noticed when I define a virtual destructor for one of the abstract class, it added one byte to the .bss segment.

I can't figure out the reason as to why and I don't think that one byte is because of the vtable. Can someone give some possible explanation to what that one byte is for? Also how I can avoid it since I just want only a text section.

Comment: You should be able to generate a linker map file that tells you what symbol corresponds to that byte.

Comment: The symbol for that one byte in the map file is the abstract class where I added the virtual destructor to.

Comment: Maybe vtables are stored in .bss. In fact I can't really think of why they would be in any other section.

Comment: Why would the vtable suddenly be stored in .bss when I had pure virtual methods in the abstract class before I added the destructor? I thought it would already created a vtable for those methods.

Comment: What compiler and version?

Comment: Green Hills compiler 4.0